como puedo pasar un parametro de express a sql azure
hola estaoy haciendo un login en react.js vite este mi codigo del frontend
try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ username, password }),
      });

      if (!response.ok) {
        const errorData = await response.json();
        throw new Error(errorData.error || 'Error en el servidor');
      }

este es mi db.js



 `export async function executeStoredProcedure(spName, params) {
      let connection;
      try {
        connection = await getConnection();
        const request = new sql.Request(connection);
    
        if (params && params.length > 0) {
          params.forEach(param => {
            if (param.value !== undefined && param.value !== null) {
              const paramName = param.name.startsWith('@') ? param.name : `@${param.name}`;
              console.log(`Añadiendo parámetro: ${paramName} con valor: ${param.value}`);
              request.input(paramName, param.type, param.value);
            } else {
              console.warn(`Parámetro '${param.name}' es undefined o null. Se omitirá.`);
            }
          });
        }
    
      
        return result.recordset;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado ${spName}:`, error);
        throw error;
      }
    }

y este mi controller
`const result = await executeStoredProcedure('SEL_obtenerHashContraseña', [
      { name: '@usuario', type: sql.VarChar(255), value: username }
    ]);`

el problema es que se conecta a la bd y todo pero al momento de enviar el parametro me lanza el siguiente error y probe de varias formas y es el mismo error siempre, y tengo otra pagina que realiza una consulta para traer categorias y funciona perfecto pero en esa no se envia parametros.

Intentando login para usuario: Admin
Conexión a la base de datos establecida
Añadiendo parámetro: @usuario con valor: Admin
Ejecutando procedimiento almacenado: SEL_obtenerHashContraseña
Parámetros: [
{
"name": "@usuario",
"type": {
"length": 255
},
"value": "Admin"
}
]
Error al ejecutar el procedimiento almacenado SEL_obtenerHashContraseña: RequestError: Procedure or function 'SEL_obtenerHashContraseña' expects parameter '@usuario', which was not supplied.

